# Fictional Ordinals

Tags: set-theory

First, since all ordinals can be represented as sets, let's extend this to well-ordered proper classes. Take the proper class of all ordinals, for example, and assign this to the 'fictional' ordinal $\Omega$ (Absolute Infinity).

Then, let's try $\Omega + 1$, $\Omega + 2$, ..., $\Omega \times 2$, ..., then continue replacing $\omega$ with $\Omega$. Then the 'limit' of these 'fictional' ordinals would be $\Omega_1$ (Absolute One Infinity). $\Omega_1$ is the analogue of $\Omega$, but with $\Omega$ instead of $\omega$.

Then create a analogue of $\Omega$ but with $\Omega_1$ instead of $\omega$. This is $\Omega_2$ (Absolute Two Infinity).

Then we can also have $\Omega_3, \Omega_4, ..., \Omega_\Omega, ..., \Omega_{\Omega_\Omega} = \Omega \;\text{x} \;3, ..., \Omega \;\text{x}\; \Omega$ etc.

Question: Has anyone ever made a similar system for well-ordered proper classes? If so, how?

(Credit for Mathis R.V for these number names and notations, and some definitions)

Comment: Your "fictional ordinal" has a fundamental issue: Do they exist? What can we say about the existence of $\Omega_1$? 
Regarding your concept, it was well-studied under the name *class well-orders.* You may find relevant questions and answers from this website or Mathoverflow. (Also, just for curiosity, could you cite references for the notations and definitions?)

Comment: Oh. I definitely asked about that before. I think on MathOverflow. [Yup, there it is.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/116590/7206)